# Network drive launched application randomly crashes on Windows 10 (1703/1809) reporting 0xc0000006 exception or error "Unable to process error"

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, crash, windows-server-2016

### Introduction

On **Windows 10 (update 1703 or 1809)**, applications launched from a network drive crashes after period of **60** to **95** minutes. On Windows 7 applications runs flawlessly.

Behaviour has been under lab surveillance for several weeks, involving both several 32 bit and 16 bit applications.

### Symptoms

- All attempts to launch applications from network drive succeed;
- All affected 32 bit applications EXE/DLL (**Powerbuilder**) logged an **0xc0000006** exception on **Event Viewer**.
- On 16 bit application (**Foxpro 2.6 for MS-DOS**), occurs error "**Unable to process error**" or simply breaks and exits.
- Once in a while "**Fatal error 104 while attempting to report error 104**" occured.
- Failure happens even during continuous usage (no significant inactivity period occurs);
- Failure only occured on **Windows 10** 32 bit/64 bit workstations either running Update 1703 or Update 1809. Windows 7 workstations were fine.
- Gathered analysis points to "safe" random period from **60** to **95** minutes between first launch and break occurs;
- Using **Wireshark**, error **STATUS_NETWORK_SESSION_EXPIRED** is consistently logged at failure ocurrs on some scenarios.
- When several instances were launched at different times, they all failed at the same second;
- A instance launch from a local drive runs fine, even after an eventual fail on network drive launched instances;
- All afected sites servers are running on **Windows 2016 Server**;
- Network drive seems functional after fails;
- Network connectivity never seems to fail (continuous PINGs) before, during or after application breaks;

### Tested lab system configurations

- Windows Server 2016 Essentials (1607)
- Windows 10 32 bit / 64 bit (update 1703 / 1809)
- Windows 7 (32 bit only)
- Cable
- Switch

### Server network configuration

Results of Powershell's `Get-SMBServerConfiguration` command:

```
AnnounceComment                 : 
AnnounceServer                  : False
AsynchronousCredits             : 512
AuditSmb1Access                 : False
AutoDisconnectTimeout           : 999999
AutoShareServer                 : True
AutoShareWorkstation            : True
CachedOpenLimit                 : 10
DurableHandleV2TimeoutInSeconds : 180
EnableAuthenticateUserSharing   : False
EnableDownlevelTimewarp         : False
EnableForcedLogoff              : True
EnableLeasing                   : False
EnableMultiChannel              : True
EnableOplocks                   : True
EnableSecuritySignature         : True
EnableSMB1Protocol              : True
EnableSMB2Protocol              : True
EnableStrictNameChecking        : True
EncryptData                     : False
IrpStackSize                    : 15
KeepAliveTime                   : 2
MaxChannelPerSession            : 32
MaxMpxCount                     : 50
MaxSessionPerConnection         : 16384
MaxThreadsPerQueue              : 20
MaxWorkItems                    : 1
NullSessionPipes                : netlogon,samr,lsarpc
NullSessionShares               : 
OplockBreakWait                 : 35
PendingClientTimeoutInSeconds   : 120
RejectUnencryptedAccess         : True
RequireSecuritySignature        : True
ServerHidden                    : True
Smb2CreditsMax                  : 8192
Smb2CreditsMin                  : 512
SmbServerNameHardeningLevel     : 0
TreatHostAsStableStorage        : False
ValidateAliasNotCircular        : True
ValidateShareScope              : True
ValidateShareScopeNotAliased    : True
ValidateTargetName              : True
```

### Workstation network configuration

Results of Powershell's `Get-SMBClientConfiguration` command:

```
ConnectionCountPerRssNetworkInterface : 4
DirectoryCacheEntriesMax              : 16
DirectoryCacheEntrySizeMax            : 65536
DirectoryCacheLifetime                : 0
DormantFileLimit                      : 1023
EnableBandwidthThrottling             : True
EnableByteRangeLockingOnReadOnlyFiles : True
EnableInsecureGuestLogons             : True
EnableLargeMtu                        : True
EnableLoadBalanceScaleOut             : True
EnableMultiChannel                    : True
EnableSecuritySignature               : False
ExtendedSessionTimeout                : 1000
FileInfoCacheEntriesMax               : 64
FileInfoCacheLifetime                 : 0
FileNotFoundCacheEntriesMax           : 128
FileNotFoundCacheLifetime             : 5
KeepConn                              : 65535
MaxCmds                               : 50
MaximumConnectionCountPerServer       : 32
OplocksDisabled                       : False
RequireSecuritySignature              : False
SessionTimeout                        : 65535
UseOpportunisticLocking               : False
WindowSizeThreshold                   : 8
```

### What we had already done

- Checked **Event Viewer**, even on SMBCLIENT and SMBSERVER sub-events, but unable to find correlation between events and application failure.
- Tried setting SMB **SessionTimeout** setting to **65535** on workstation follow by reboot, as pointed by [harryc](https://superuser.com/a/1418929/56033);
- Tried setting SMB **Keepcon** setting to **65535** on workstation follow by reboot;
- Disabled autodisconnect (changing it to -1) followed by a reboot;
- Tried enabling **SMB1** on both server/workstation followed by a reboot;
- Tried disabling antivirus (ESET) on both server/workstation followed by a reboot;
- Disabled powersaving network on card both server/workstation followed by a reboot;
- Tried disabling firewall on both server/workstation;
- Case has been under lab surveilance for weeks with no success.

Is there anyone else facing the symptons and able to provide alternative solutions?

Thanks for you attention

Comment: This might help you https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: I forgot to mention that we've also used Process Monitor, but it provided no complementary clues regarding to Wireshark info. It seems every exe/dll opened thats kept opened for more that 60 minutes is afftected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, one new bug was introduced in Windows 10 1809, acknowledged
by Microsoft in the article
[Mapped network drive may fail to reconnect in Windows 10, version 1809](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/4471218/mapped-network-drive-may-fail-to-reconnect-in-windows-10-version-1809).

While Microsoft is aware of the problem, a permanent fix isn't expected
until sometime in 2019. In the meantime, if this is indeed your problem,
you may use the workaround offered in the article to mitigate the bug.

Below I have listed some other workarounds proposed by users on Internet forums.

---

Try to set on the client the value of `SessionTimeout` to 65535 seconds.
This can be done using the PowerShell command
[Set-SmbClientConfiguration -SessionTimeout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/set-smbclientconfiguration?view=win10-ps).

It may also live in the registry at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CURRENTCONTROLSET\SERVICES\ LANMANWORKSTATION\PARAMETERS\SESSTIMEOUT`
(see this [old link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/102067/sesstimeout-information)).

I suggest rebooting afterward.

---

Other possible workarounds:

- Change the group policy to *Update* rather than *Replace* the drive mapping,
  in the Group Policy Object (GPO):
  *User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps*.
  See [link](https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2016/08/windows-10-repeatedly-disconnects-network-drives/).
  Some people report that it can be set to *Refresh*.
- Run on server and client in elevated cmd the command:

  ```
  net config server /autodisconnect:-1
  ```
- Set the power option of the network adapter do disable
  "Allow the computer turn off this device to save power".
- Some people report that remapping the network share on login solves the
  problem, and some have added a login script for that.
- Other reports recommend disabling Windows 10 fast startup.

Comment: We already tried that, but no success. I will update my question. Since you added an answer, please consider removing (if possible) your duplicate comment.

Comment: I have added more information.

Comment: Changing the **Group Policy** to **Update** rather than **Replace** the drive mapping did solve it!

Comment: Knowing your tip enabled us to rapidly question some of our assumptions, since it allowed us to reproduce failure with a simple **gpupdate** command to update group policy. We also found why drive mapping replace policy was not affecting Windows 7 machine: applying gpupdate on Windows 7 required a session restart, while Windows 10 was able to apply policy immediately. I will update my question with new findings.

Comment: Just to point out that I do not agree with Windows 10 Update 1809 bug reference, since, beside ours tests proved it Update 1703 is also affected, I would classify it as different subjet. Anyway, you surelly deserve the bounty!

Answer (score 1):

1. If any of server/client box is running on VMWare, please update the VMware tools to 9.0.13 or above. The vmxnet3 Ethernet driver, as part of VMware tools package, should be 1.5.2 or above, otherwise it may drop packages randomly for no reason.
2. Do you have any firewall or load balancer sitting in-between? Please by-pass it then see how it goes.
3. Increasing the SESSIONTIMEOUT, mentioned by harrymc, is a good approach. I will do the same. But I will also do these for testing purpose:

Download TCP Optimizer 4.0, change these settings on both client and server sides the reboot both boxes:
Increase both MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server and MaxConnectionPerServer to 240, 
Increase Max SYNC Retransmissions to 7
MaxUserPort to 65534
TCPTimedWaitDelay to 180

Logon client box, mount the network drive by its IP address as \192.168.100.xxx\Source_folder then run the same app to test it.

If problem keeps going on, please share what app you are running. If it is a Java apps, it may require some tuning. 
Wish you luck and looking forward to know how it goes.